# Email configuration for post-build in Jenkins: Where can I find the Server name and port number?

Tags: email, selenium, jenkins

I need the following information to set up automatic-email notifications in Jenkins using my office email, when I run selenium test scripts in Jenkins .
1. SMTP server name
2. SMTP server port number

Where can I find the Server name and port number.
Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This information has nothing to do with Jenkins. You need to ask your IT/Email administrator for that information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't belong on any SE site — they're asking for info only their IT department can provide.